# Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'

Tags: android, cordova, jenkins

I'm trying to build an Ionic/Cordova app for Android using Jenkins. When I try to build, it gets to near the end, then spews out

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension. One of '{codename, vendor}' is expected.
```

followed by a few hundred lines of stack, combined with similar versions for different expected things.

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Removing the `<base-extension>true</base-extension>` bits from the Android platform files (all of them).
- Clearing all the files out of the workspace and trying again.
- Rebooting after doing the above, because maybe one of the bad files was stuck in Gradle.
- Reinstalling the newest Java SDK.

I even searched everywhere I could to try to find any file containing that string, but no luck.

What's going wrong?

Misc details:
App uses Ionic 6/Angular 14 (cdk-virtual-scroll isn't ready for prime-time, so Ionic 7 is out of the question), with ionic-native plugins at 5.36.
`cordova-android` is at 10.1.2.
Ionic CLI at 6.20, Cordova CLI at 11.0.
OpenJDK 11.0.16, javac 1.8.0_382.
Build server is Rocky 8.6 on amd64.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure how to fix the invalid-content error and the stack spew, but I figured out what was actually killing the build!

It was that the `config.xml` file was missing the attribute `android-versionCode` on the top-level `widget`.

I apparently blamed the wrong thing.

The stack spew from the invalid-content error is still being made (and explanations for why it's still there are welcome), but at least the build works now.